# Error when installing mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

When installing mysqldb on mac osx 10.5:

sudo ../bin/python /Users/Awais/mysqlpython/setup.py install

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Awais/mysqlpython/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
   metadata, options = get_config()
File "/Users/Awais/mysqlpython/setup_posix.py", line 32, in get_config
   metadata, options = get_metadata_and_options()
File "/Users/Awais/mysqlpython/setup_common.py", line 7, in get_metadata_and_options metadata = dict(config.items('metadata'))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ConfigParser.py",    line 564, in items
raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'metadata'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are installing MySQL for Python but you have to have MySQL installed first. So, first download the MySQL installer from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and install it and then try installing MySQL for Python.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have found out the actual reason. MySQL was already installed prior to this, but I had to go inside the mysqldb setup directory first and then run the python instance from the virtual environment.

Comment: Installed MySql server with developer option, still has problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying port an older Linux server RH EL 5 Workstation to CentOS 6.4 64-bit. One of the two things I have had to do -- because it had been a while since I had built a Python-based MySQL server -- was make sure mysql-devel was installed, and from the menu-software install, as well as MySQL-python was installed.

The advantage to installing MySQL-python this way that the CentOS 6.4 distribution matches MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.el6.x86_64 matches the version of MySQL installed  5.1.69.

Prior to this, I tried building and installing MySQL-python with no success. In a perfect world, I would figure out why, but, like many things, I am on a deadline, and this worked, and was also recommended in posts I read both on SO and elsewhere.